# Creating Asana Project using API leaves name and notes blank

Tags: asana

I working on a VB.NET program to that will create an ASANA project using the API.  I am able to create a project but the name and notes for the project are blank.

Here is my url:
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/teams/22956925957833/projects

Here is the json I am passing:
{"data":[{"name":"Randy Test Project","notes":"Randy Test Project Notes"}]}

Here is the json response back:

{"data":{"id":23081257887338,"created_at":"2014-12-29T22:36:43.891Z","modified_at":"2014-12-29T22:36:43.891Z","public":true,"name":"","notes":"","archived":false,"workspace":{"id":5272875888767,"name":"summitmarketing.com"},"members":[{"id":11674220097573,"name":"Randy Gress"}],"followers":[{"id":11674220097573,"name":"Randy Gress"}],"color":null,"team":{"id":22956925957833,"name":"Test Team For Randy"}}}

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` field is an array containing a single hash. It should just be a hash.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  Thanks
Here is the JSON I should have sent
{"data":{"name":"Randy Test Project","notes":"Randy Test Project Notes"}}